# Laravel 8 Find Method result 404 Not Found

Tags: laravel, methods, find, crud

I just start learning Laravel 8, In my learning project I am using find($id) Method but it ended with 404 Not Found. In my database id is the primary key.

Here are the code I wrote

```
<td>
    <a href="/detail/{{$data->id}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-round btn-primary" class="btn btn-primary">Detail</a>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-sm btn-round btn-warning">Update</a>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-sm btn-round btn-danger">Delete</a>
</td>
```

For Controller :

```
public function show($id)
{
    $detail = Member::find($id);
    return response()->json($detail);
}
```

Route :

```
Route::get('/detail/id', [MemberController::class, 'show']);
```

Please help me, what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing curly brackets `{id}` in the route definition

```
Route::get('/detail/{id}', [MemberController::class, 'show']);
```

```
public function show($id)
{
    return Member::findOrFail($id);
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-parameters

You can also use route model binding

In your case it will be

```
Route::get('/detail/{member}', [MemberController::class, 'show']);
```

```
public function show(Member $member)
{
    return $member;
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-model-binding

Comment: @GlenDPMaramis I like it when people mark a working solution.